# Using Azure Active Directory to authenticate specific user access to generic devices

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, iot, windows-10-iot-core

We would like to distribute generic devices that automatically connect to the Azure IoT platform - this we can do.

However we are looking for a way to allow the owners of these devices to send commands to them securely, to do this the devices would need to be registered to their owner, so that only they can access them.

We can use the Azure Active Directory platform to create user names for the owners - how could we then link the devices from the IoT platform to the respective user name of the owner? Is this possible?

Each device is preconfigured, so we were thinking of programming each device with a unique identifier that could be used by the customer to find their device and "claim" it from the IoT hub on the cloud, but we would love to hear any other thoughts and suggestions.